# About the null space in the uv editor?

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

Hi there I have a question, 
I have seen in some post about people who makes very well their jobs with UV , I think useful way to earn space and give more resolution to the final texture (diffuse map for example)

see this picture I think it is well ( the blank space ,in color black is a Null space for UV coordinate right?) .
[http://imgur.com/a/5K2ps](https://imgur.com/a/5K2ps)

let's check my workflow for this asset I had made.
 (not bad , but I think I just left enough blank space? , not clever too be useful in pixels resolution).
[http://imgur.com/a/ZzWwQ](https://imgur.com/a/ZzWwQ)

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking..? Are you looking for ways to optimize UV packing? (to minimize wasted space?)

Comment: yes! cause I had noticed some people reduce that "blank" space, I think to increase the resolution, more pixels area more details.